# Why are Cardiff and Wales apparently host to so much of the English legal sector?

Tags: england-and-wales

I'm guessing this is going to be contentious but very likely ultimately in scope here though not completely certain.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this doesn't seem to be within the scope of Law.SE. It might be a better fit for History.SE. In the alternative, this needs clarification and citation.

Comment: Cite examples that have been closed upon actual discussions with articulated reasons.

Comment: Please read [on-topic](https://law.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). Which of the following categories do you propose your question belong to? * Statutes or court decisions * Legal terms and language, doctrines and theory * Legal process and procedure * Historical legal applications * Dealing with legal professionals * Legal training, education, and qualifications

Comment: Also, I implore you to reread the [How do I ask a good question?](https://law.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) - This question, as presented: 1) shows no research. 2) is very unspecific 3) does not show relevancy in any way 4) the body actually only contains a meta comment that the question would be on topic.

Comment: I have not voted on the question based on the idea that this *might* be a relevant question if fleshed out in some way. For example, you could show the pattern of lawyers congregating to these regions and then ask if there is something in legal history that might have resulted in it  (making it part of the historical legal applications). As presented, however, I see a question, the claim that it might be on-topic (without supporting it), and nothing that even supports that the pattern alleged in the question is actually something that exists.

Comment: I would say that it is quite arguably related to dealing with legal professionals in that by better understanding the landscape of the industry it better equips one to navigate and deal with it. In the same vein there was at some point a speculative question about why a firm *might have* decided to argue a supreme court case with a single (junior) barrister, barring mere costs as an acceptable answer. Which of those questions does that answer fall into? It's simply about people helping each other enrich their overall understandings of the field. I don't understand why certain users seem

Comment: Rather so committed to presenting impediments to people who wish to use this platform to exchange perfectly thoughtful information with one another especially when it takes much less effort to not obstruct the exchange than to obstruct it.

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by "so much"? Do you mean in terms of legal professionals, or court cases, or regulations, or something else? It would also be helpful if you could provide some examples.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They aren't.

From a [2019 Welsh government report](https://gov.wales/sites/default/files/publications/2019-10/the-legal-sector-in-wales-a-rapid-review.pdf),

> In comparison with England, Wales is somewhat underserved on a “law firm per head of population” basis. The SRA
> estimates that, when nationwide general populations are compared, there is one law firm per 5,472 people in England,
> compared with one law firm per 7,962 people in Wales. (p11)

The report cites 3500 practicing solicitors, which compares to about 150000 in England and Wales in total (using [2019 figures](https://www.sra.org.uk/sra/research-publications/regulated-community-statistics/data/population_solicitors/) from the SRA). The population of Wales in 2019 was 3.1m and England was 56.2m, so there are also fewer solicitors per capita in Wales compared to England.

In the same year, there were about 17000 practicing barristers in England and Wales, of which about 300 were in Wales. This is a similar ratio as for solicitors (report p18).

The English numbers are very heavily skewed by London. If we compare Wales to a given region of England other than London, it comes out more favourably.

Within Wales, Cardiff hosts a disproportionate number of lawyers (p11 of the report). It is the seat of the Welsh government and responsible for an outsized contribution to the Welsh economy: 12% of the population, 20% share of Welsh gross value added, 30% of the law firms.

The report does identify some specific examples of large legal practices or well-regarded barristers' chambers. But overall, Wales does not seem to have a disproportionate share of the legal sector. London *does*, and Wales is more comparable to non-London parts of England, supporting a typical number of lawyers doing local work, plus a few higher-profile outliers.